# Trying to log in facebook using secure social

Tags: facebook, scala, securesocial

I'm receiving the following error

```
{
```

"error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}

I created my app in facebook and set the url site like this...

[image: Url Setup]

When I clicked in the icon of facebook to log in and get the following url

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?scope=email&client_id={MyKey}&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fauth%2Fauthenticate%2Ffacebook&response_type=code&state=7d2d6abf-b7d2-4b5c-b956-7d7487d89cbd

I'm following the example https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/master/samples/scala

I would like the documentation will be available soon. :)

So, I don't really know where I should start looking for... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Well... Facebook servers need to know the `public ip` of your server to send the user back to your server once the authentication is done.

On our computers when we say `localhost`, it is configured to translate to the `loopback ip address` that is - `127.0.0.1` which computer understand as `My own ip address` ( whatever your ip address may be, your computer will map `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` to itslef. ).

Now, similarly for facebook's server `localhost` translate to itslef. And people at facebook are wise enough to know that this is not what you want, and probably did this by mistake. So they tell you that you have provided an invalid redirect url.

You need to make sure that your server has a `public IP` and then provide your public IP to facebook api. Or, you can buy a domain name such as `myawesoemfacebookfacingnewsite.com` and have it mapped to the `public IP` of your server on some `DNS` provider, then you can provide your domain name to facebook API.

Also... even for your own computer there is can not be a `localhost.com`, just the `localhost`. And if you configured a `virtual host` mapped to `localhost.com` in your `Apache conf`, it will work `"just" for you, not for the outside world`. Also, please don't do that... having a `virtual host` named `localhost.com` is kind of embarrassing and not recommended.